# using cygwin bash functions in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, cygwin

I am using the following bash function in cygwin .bashrc (to return windows styed paths)

```
pwd() {
  cygpath -m "`command pwd`"
}
export pwd
```

So when I run pwd from bash, I get the result in windows style path. However, if I use `pwd` in Makefile, then I get cygwin style results

```
run:
    echo `pwd`
```

Can anyone please suggest me on how to make it work in the Makefile.

P.S: I can't use cygpath, this sample problem is just depicting one of the problem from my larger problem set.

Comment: Is the question how to get things from your `.bashrc` file to be available in make recipes? Or is the question something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507641/functions-in-makefile) or [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109242/cannot-call-bash-function-inside-makefile)

Comment: As an aside, `echo \`pwd\` ` is [Useless Use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) and better written simply `pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem. My way to debug would be:

1) remove the custom `pwd` function from `.bashrc`

2) restart Cygwin

3) call `type cygpath` and keep the output.

4) call `pwd` and keep the output.

5) call and keep the output of:

```
cygpath -m `pwd`
```

6) Create and run this Makefile

```
all:
    @echo "type cygpath is: `type cygpath`"
```

7) Are the outputs of 3) and 6) are the same? if yes, go to next step.

8) Create and run this Makefile:

```
all:
    @echo "pwd is: `pwd`"
```

8) Are the outputs of 4) and 8) are the same? if yes, go to next step.

9) Create and run this Makefile:

```
all:
    @PWD=`pwd`; echo "Windows cygpath is: `cygpath -m $$PWD`"
```

10) Is this what you want?